# Elixir | How do I assign variable to a range of numbers and create several if statement

Tags: elixir

I am trying to find odd, even and divisible by 3 numbers from 1-100, I can not find a way to assign `enum.list_to(1, 100)` to even show up all the way (it stops at 50).

So here is what I'm trying to do. I just assign the variable so I can create a scenario behind the variable.

```
num = (Enum.to_list 1..100)
```

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,
>   20, 21, 22,  23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36,
>   37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42,  43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, ...]

Comment: The Elixir shell (iex) will truncate long expressions by default. If you use `IO.puts num` you should see the full list.

Comment: Try to run this in iex
`nums = (Enum.to_list 1..100)`
and it will output this - which is what you are getting.
`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22,
 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42,
 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, ...]`. If you try to look at the number of elements this list has it will give 100
`iex(5)> nums |> Enum.count` will output
`100`

Answer (score 4):

The console by default limits the number of items it displays to 50. You can configure the number of items displayed by passing the `limit` option to [`inspect/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#inspect/2):

```elixir
iex(1)> Enum.to_list(1..100) |> inspect(limit: :infinity)
```

Result:

`"[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]"`

Here's an example of how you can implement the algorithm using [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3) (this is just one way, there are many ways to do it!):

```elixir
Enum.reduce(1..100, %{odd: [], even: [], three: []}, fn i, groups ->
  odd = if (rem(i, 2) == 1), do: [i | groups.odd], else: groups.odd
  even = if (rem(i, 2) == 0), do: [i | groups.even], else: groups.even
  three = if (rem(i, 3) == 0), do: [i | groups.three], else: groups.three
  %{odd: odd, even: even, three: three}
end)
```

And the result (again, you can use `inspect(limit: :infinity)` if you want to see all of the numbers:

```elixir
%{
  even: [100, 98, 96, 94, 92, 90, 88, 86, 84, 82, 80, 78, 76, 74, 72, 70, 68,
   66, 64, 62, 60, 58, 56, 54, 52, 50, 48, 46, 44, 42, 40, 38, 36, 34, 32, 30,
   28, 26, 24, 22, 20, 18, 16, 14, 12, 10, 8, 6, 4, ...],
  odd: [99, 97, 95, 93, 91, 89, 87, 85, 83, 81, 79, 77, 75, 73, 71, 69, 67, 65,
   63, 61, 59, 57, 55, 53, 51, 49, 47, 45, 43, 41, 39, 37, 35, 33, 31, 29, 27,
   25, 23, 21, 19, 17, 15, 13, 11, 9, 7, 5, ...],
  three: [99, 96, 93, 90, 87, 84, 81, 78, 75, 72, 69, 66, 63, 60, 57, 54, 51,
   48, 45, 42, 39, 36, 33, 30, 27, 24, 21, 18, 15, 12, 9, 6, 3]
}
```